# How do I get a µ character out of sqlite and onto a web-page?

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode, utf-8

On a Python driven web app using a sqlite datastore I had this error:

> Could not decode to UTF-8 column
>   'name' with text '300µL-10-10'

Reading [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects) it looks like I need to switch my text-factory to str and get bytestrings but when I do this my html output looks like this:

> 300�L-10-10

I do have my content-type set as:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: It seems like Py is outputting the character as something it doesn't know rather than outputting the actual character to the browser, so changing the content-type wouldn't fix that. Make sure that the string that Py is outputting is actually mu.

Comment: Have it display the repr() of the string, in order to see what the non-ASCII characters are. That should help you figure out where the en/decoding error comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the data in your datastore is not encoded as UTF-8; instead, it's probably either latin-1 or cp1252.  To decode it automatically, try setting Connection.text_factory to your own function:

```
def convert_string(s):
    try:
        u = s.decode("utf-8")
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        u = s.decode("cp1252")
    return u

conn.text_factory = convert_string
```

Comment: Word of caution if you want to adapt this recipe: cp1252 and latin-1 will both succesfully decode any bytestring, so you can't add more 'alternatives' after them.

Comment: That would have produced a question mark rather than `xFFFD`.

Comment: @Thomas: there are bytes `cp1252` won't decode, though not that many. (`iso-8859-1` of course does map every byte.)

Comment: @bobince: Ah, yes, forgot about those five bytes that cp1252 doesn't decode.

Comment: @BalusC: U+FFFD ('REPLACEMENT CHARACTER') is the thing used instead of a questionmark in unicode, when failing to decode a bytesequence correctly (using the 'replace' error handler.) A questionmark is only used when you use the 'replace' error handler while encoding to bytestring.

Comment: @eswald, this worked like a charm.  I think the key to your answer is "data in your datastore is not encoded as UTF-8".  I need to go back and fix that. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark: Glad it helped.  The good news about this particular recipe is that you can do the conversion at your leisure, without having to update the code at the exact same time.